# Run in parallel

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a chatbot with Speech Recognition module, and I've put together some lines of code as follows:

```
def recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone):
    """Transcribe speech from recorded from `microphone`.

    Returns a dictionary with three keys:
    "success": a boolean indicating whether or not the API request was
               successful
    "error":   `None` if no error occured, otherwise a string containing
               an error message if the API could not be reached or
               speech was unrecognizable
    "transcription": `None` if speech could not be transcribed,
               otherwise a string containing the transcribed text
    """
    # check that recognizer and microphone arguments are appropriate type
    if not isinstance(recognizer, sr.Recognizer):
        raise TypeError("`recognizer` must be `Recognizer` instance")

    if not isinstance(microphone, sr.Microphone):
        raise TypeError("`microphone` must be `Microphone` instance")

    # adjust the recognizer sensitivity to ambient noise and record audio
    # from the microphone
    with microphone as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        recognizer.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    # set up the response object
    response = {
        "success": True,
        "error": None,
        "transcription": None
    }

    # try recognizing the speech in the recording
    # if a RequestError or UnknownValueError exception is caught,
    #     update the response object accordingly
    try:
        response["transcription"] = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-PT')
    except sr.RequestError:
        # API was unreachable or unresponsive
        response["success"] = False
        response["error"] = "API unavailable"
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        # speech was unintelligible
        response["error"] = "Unable to recognize speech"

    return response

clip_1.preview() #1
result = recognize_speech_from_mic(recognizer, microphone) #2
clip_7.preview() #3
print(result) #4
```

My question is that I would like line #2 (result = recognize_speech_from_mic) to run at the same time as the previous (clip_1.preview()). The clip is a mp4 clip that runs on PyGame window.

Thank you in advance